# Lock DB2 for IBM i (AS400) record from java

Tags: java, sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm trying to lock db2(as400) record from java after retrieve the value.I want to block the record from other users.

Is this possible.

Comment: Maybe http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/html/as400/v4r4/ic2924/info/db2/rbafomst111.htm you should tell us if you are using jdbc or jt400

Comment: JT400 includes JDBC, so are you using SQL or RLA?  A Code sample would be helpful.

Comment: @ Charles I'm trying to do it using SQL . Upto now I have no code.

Comment: I would think a select for update would do it.  Discussion here: http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1698118-DB2-SELECT-for-UPDATE-because-of-concurrency-issue